# Expressing Rebates as an Equation

Tags: functions

How would you go about expressing/modelling rebates in an equation? For example, say a store normally sells t-shirts for \$6.00, but this month they will give you \$2.00 back when you buy a t-shirt. Meaning, if I have \$20.00 then I can buy 3 shirts with my starting money, and a 4th using my three \$2.00 rebates, thus leaving me with 4 shirts and $4.00 in my pocket.

Initial intuition made me think it would simply be $f(x) = x/4$, but this doesn't work, which makes sense since the shirts aren't actually discounted. I then came up with $f(x) = x/6 + (2x/36)$. But this also falls apart once you get into situations where the shirts you buy with your rebated money give you enough money to buy even more shirts.

So, if I have an original price $a$, a rebate $b$ (where $a > b$), and a starting balance of $x$, how many things can I buy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \text{# of shirts}=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{6}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{(x-6\cdot\lfloor\frac{x}{6}\rfloor)+2\cdot\lfloor\frac{x}{6}\rfloor}{6}\right\rfloor,$$where $x$ is the initial amount of money you have... In your case, $x=\$20$. $\$6$ is the price of the shirt, and the separate $2$ above represents the amount of the rebate.

To be clear, you would have to continue the equation on in a similar pattern. This particular equation tells you how many shirts you can buy initially AND with the rebates from the initial purchase. Perhaps you can buy more shirts with rebates from the rebate-purchases, though, so on and so forth. A series representing such a pattern is given by $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty n_k$$ where $$n_{1}=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{6}\right\rfloor,\qquad n_{k+1}=\left\lfloor\frac{(x-6(n_1+\cdots+n_k)+2(n_1+\cdots+n_k)}{6}\right\rfloor.$$ For $k$ large enough, this quantity will be $0$.

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? I plugged it into WolframAlpha, and it doesn't appear to get the correct answer for $x= 57$, which I believe is $13$. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+floor(x+%2F+6)+%2B+floor(((x+-+6+*+floor(x+%2F+6))+%2B+2+*+floor(x+%2F+6))+%2F+6)+for+x+%3D+57).

Comment: @rolledback: In that case, you have to add an additional term for the rebate-rebate-purchases (you have enough money left over after the rebate-purchases to buy another round of shirts...this is what is meant that a similar pattern has to be continued).

Comment: Ah, my mistake, my brain failed to read the end of your original answer. Thank you for coming back and detailing out the exact series. Very much appreciated. :)


Follow up question, do you think it'd be possible to know how many rounds of shirt buying would be possible before completing the series?